# I want to run PHP script onclick event of button tag is it possible

Tags: php

Here is the code that I want to run...the calculation is in PHP and I want it to run on onclick event of the button tag.

```
 <button onclick = "myFunction()"> Click here to calculate</button>
  <script> 
  function myFunction()
  { <?php $x = 100; $y = 2;
   echo "This is multiplication of x and y ="." ". $x*$y."</br>"; 
   echo "This is addition of x and y ="." ".($x + $y)."</br>";
   echo "This is subtraction of x and y ="." ".($x - $y)."</br>"; 
   echo "This is division of x and y = "." " .$x/$y."</br>";
   echo "This is remainder of x and y ="." ". $x % $y."</br>"; ?>
 }
 myFunction();
 </script>
```

is this possible ?
please help me out..

Comment: Yes you can do it. just use jquery click event and do it.

Comment: please help me out with syntax i am new to it..

Comment: I'd rather use Ajax to call a PHP script that'll do your calculation in the background. It'd be a cleaner way.

Comment: this is not working??

Comment: agree with @D4V1D use ajax for this type of functionality

Comment: I'm probably missing something here, because I still fail to see how or why anybody would use PHP/AJAX to do anything like this, when it seems clear that it should be done with simple JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As you ask for help, Please check this:-**

1:- create an HTML file

```
    <html>
    <script src = "jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <button id ="click_button"> Click here to calculate</button>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#click_button').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'buttonclick.php',
                success: function(Response){
                    alert(Response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
     </html>
```

2:- create a PHP file (with name buttonclick.php):-

```
<?php 

  function myFunction()
  { 

   $x = 100; $y = 2;

   echo "This is multiplication of x and y ="." ". $x*$y."</br>"; 

   echo "This is addition of x and y ="." ".($x + $y)."</br>";

   echo "This is subtraction of x and y ="." ".($x - $y)."</br>"; 

   echo "This is division of x and y = "." " .$x/$y."</br>";

   echo "This is remainder of x and y ="." ". $x % $y."</br>";

 }
 return myFunction();

?>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/6l56dq

**Note:-** both file (html and php) and jquery file(jquery-1.9.1.js) will be in same working directory. Also it depends on you how you want to show response. I just gave you an example to understand easily.

Answer (score 2):

There is some confusion in your question.

PHP is a server side script language, so it is executed before the page is rendered on the browser.

This means that you function is executed in the server and not when the user clicks.

If you want to execute some computation at the moment of the click, you should use javascript, because it is the language that is understood by browsers.

If you want to use PHP to compute values, you should use AJAX. To do it you could use jquery methods like `$.ajax()`, `$.get()` or `$.post()`

Comment: Thank you very much...using javascript i am able to do it but i need it to do in PHP but I got ur point...Thanks

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed then you must use AJAX, it's the only way